# Does anyone have a data sheet for MC16-0072

Tags: pwm

I can't seem to relibly find data sheets for MCM electronics parts.. Searched for hours.. Any help?

Comment: not really an arduino question, could possibly be better served in the electronics stack exchange... But it could be betetr answered if you described the item and packaging and/or a pic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack exchange is not a human replacement for google when you are not able to get search results.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search gave me the impression that MC16-0072 is actually some sort of rebranding. It seems MCM is not the manufacturer, simply a distributor.

Does the hardware itself have any number or serial printed on it?

In any case, when I dug a bit deeper and found [this datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/168101.pdf?_ga=1.88928286.403328245.1468222988). However, without an image of your hardware or its serial number, I cannot confirm the datasheet is for your hardware.